# What is 'seven-headed bull' in the dialogue between King and Queen?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phrase-meaning

The following is an excerpt from the First Act (The Princess and the Woodcutter) of *Make Believe*, a play for children, written by A. A. Milne in 1918. Could someone help me understand this play clearly and fully by answering two questions?

Q1. I cannot imagine anything from the expression of ‘the seven-headed bull’. Is this a kind of fortuneteller, wearing something of seven-headed bull, or an animal god?

Q2. In the fairy tales of prince-hunting, interest in one’s meals or appetite has played an important role?

> QUEEN: It is a pity that the seven-headed bull died last year.
>
> KING. Yes, he had a way of sorting out competitors for the hand of our beloved one that was beyond all praise. One could have felt quite
> sure that, had the three competitors been introduced to him, only one
> of them would have taken any further interest in the matter.
>
> QUEEN (always the housekeeper): And even he mightn't have taken any interest in his meals.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about a literary rather than a language matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [*Once on a Time* by A.A Milne](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/27771/27771-h/27771-h.htm):

> To tell the truth, Coronel was a little jealous of his friend. A
> certain Prince Perivale, who had stayed at his uncle's court, had once
> been a suitor for Hyacinth's hand; but losing a competition with the
> **famous *seven-headed bull*** of Euralia, which Merriwig had arranged for
> him, had made no further headway with his suit.

Another instance:

> "Ah, well, no doubt they were unsuccessful. No matter, dear, we can easily find you plenty more suitors. Indeed, the subject has been very near my thoughts lately. We'll arrange a little competition, and let them know in the neighbouring countries; there'll be no lack of candidates. Let me see, there's ***that seven-headed bull***; he's getting a little old now, but he was good enough for the last one. We might——"
>
> "I don't want a suitor," said Hyacinth softly. "I have one."
>
> Merriwig leant forward with eagerness.
>
> "My dear, this is indeed news. Tell me all about it. Upon what quest did you send him?"
>
> Hyacinth had felt this coming. Had she lived in modern times she would have expected the question, "What is his income?" A man must prove his worth in some way.
>
> "I haven't sent him away at all yet," she said; "he's only just come. He's been very kind to me, and I'm sure you'll love him."
>
> "Well, well, we'll arrange something for him. Perhaps ***that bull*** I was speaking of—— By the way, who is he?"

So, to answer your first question, it seems like the "seven-headed bull" is in fact a bull with seven heads meant to serve as a competition for the Princes.

---

Some more (possibly irrelevant) info...

In *The Princess and the Woodcutter*, the Princess says:

> PRINCESS. Why, of course! You should read the History Books,
> Woodcutter. The suitors to the hand of a Princess are always set some
> trial of strength or test of quality by the King, and the winner
> marries his daughter.

Since the "seven-headed bull" had died, the competition in this specific Act was to discover the Prince with the kindest heart:

> KING (with a sigh). However, those days are over. We must think of a
> new test. Somehow I think that, in a son-in-law, moral worth is even
> more to be desired than mere brute strength. Now my suggestion is
> this: that you should disguise yourself as a beggar woman and approach
> each of the three princes in turn, supplicating their charity. In this
> way we shall discover which of the three has the kindest heart. What
> do you say, my dear?

---

However, I am not sure what to make of your second question...

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer, giving me two quotations, which are surely helpful for me to understand the play.

Comment: A suitor who had been willing to fight the bull might well have ended up too badly injured to be able to eat much.

Comment: @KateBunting Particularly if one of the seven heads had gored him in the lower abdomen.